# Typescript Pick multiple keys

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface A{
  a:{
    name: string
  }
  b:{
    age: number
  }
}

type PickMultiple = ..... //todo

const child:PickMultiple<A,['a','b']> = {
   name: 'mike',
   age: 18
}
```

How can I extract multiple keys? it was same as `Pick Child key`

Ofcourse `Pick<A, 'a'| 'b'>`  can't work as expected

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
interface A {
  a: {
    name: string
  }
  b: {
    age: number
  }
}

type Picked<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K]

const a: Picked<A, 'a' | 'b'> = {
  name: '1',
  age: 18,
}
console.log(a)
```

Comment: This has the same issues as my original answer, if you leave out either `name` or `age`, Typescript will say it's valid.

Answer (score 19):

It already supports multiple keys

```
interface Todo {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
 
type TodoPreview = Pick<Todo, "title" | "completed">;
```

Comment: This is the most relevant answer to me

Comment: @SebastienH.   The OP was after something that could merge from sub types,  A['a'], A['b'], this is just picking from a flat interface Todo,.

Comment: @keith you're right, didn't see it precisely

Answer (score 4):

You can actually pick multiple keys by default

```
interface A {
  a: {
    name: string;
  };
  b: {
    age: number;
  };
}

type Picked = Pick<A, 'a' | 'b'>;
```

See full documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys

Answer (score 3):

You might be over complicating this.

> Update:
>
> Like pointed out in the comments by ' Sebastien H', my original answer
> was not totally correct, it was basically saying a or b, and due to
> duck typing having both works too.  So to make this stricter you need
> intersection type, not a union type.

How about..

```
interface A{
  a:{
    name: string
  }
  b:{
    age: number
  }
}

const child: A['a'] & A['b']= {
  name: 'Mike',
  age: 23,
}
```

With the original `A['a' | 'b']` it would allow either name or age to be left out.

ps. Doing `A['a' & 'b']` would also not be a shortcut here.

Comment: Type can even be simplified to `A['a' | 'b']`.

Comment: not working. you're basically saying typeof A['a'] or A['b'], where we're expecting an object with both keys

Comment: @SebastienH.  Good point, I've updated to use the intersection type, rather than a union type...